# How to create new Syntax Definitions for SublimeLinter 3?

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using the following linters in Sublime Text 3 (under GNU/Linux with KDE Desktop): `csslint`, `htmltidy`, `jshint` and `phplint`. All of them work very well, except on certain cases.

For example, I have a PHP file called `style.php` where first I get some options from the WordPress Settings API, then I close the PHP code and I start the HTML tag for styles: `<style type="text/css"></style>`... Inside of the `style` tag I have more PHP code, and this is the code where linters don't work.

```
<?php // PHP linter works
    $option1 = get_option( 'option_1' ); // 'phplint' works
    $option2 = get_option( 'option_2' ); // 'phplint' works
    $option3 = get_option( 'option_3' ); // 'phplint' works
?>

<style type="text/css"><!-- 'htmltidy' is not working -->
<?php // 'phplint' doesn't work here
    $body = 'body{';
    $pattern = get_option( 'option_1' );
    if ( ! empty( $option1[ 'background-color' ] ) ) {
        $body .= 'background-color:' . $option1[ 'background-color' ] . ';';
    }
    $body .= '}';
    echo $body . "\n";
?>

/* 'csslint' works perfect here */
.select1 {
    color: <?php echo $option2; ?>; /* 'phplint' doesn't work*/
}

.select2 {
    color: <?php echo $option3; ?>; /* 'phplint' doesn't work*/
}
```

So, my question is: How to create a new Syntax Definition to allow this embedded PHP into `style` tags without 700 errors? Is it possible?

This is my `syntax_map`:

```
"syntax_map": {
    "html (django)": "html",
    "html (rails)": "html",
    "html 5": "html",
    "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
    "magicpython": "python",
    "php": "html",
    "python django": "python"
},
```